# CMake does not create make file

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I am using cmake to build the project. I am new to c++ so there can be mistakes as i am unaware of how it internally works.

When i run cmake command in build directory then the response does not give any error. The output is as shown in next image.[image after cmake command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ7QI.png)

Now when i go to the `test` directory then i see these files.

[image of test directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTaoU.png)

As i already said i don't know how it internally works but following some online tutorials i expect that there should be a `make` file but i'm not getting that.

Any help would be great for as i am stucked in this setup from 3 days. 
This is what is want to do next:

First, standard build files should be created from
these configuration files:
`cd test/ && mkdir build && cd build,`
`cmake ..`
Note that you have to run these commands only once. Next, you can use your platform’s native build tools
for the actual building:
`make -j10`
And train a single decision tree or bagging classifier with:
`./DecisionTreeTest`, and
`./BaggingTest,`

Comment: CMake can use a variety of build systems. You are generating a visual studio project. You can specify what you want to use with the `-G` option. `cmake --help` should list the different generators available to you.

Comment: Looks like your default is making a lovely Visual Studio solution for you. `.sln` and `.vcxproj` files are Visual Studio solution and C++ project files respectively.

Comment: What compiler/IDE do you have installed, anyway?

Comment: @Tzalumen i have Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Do you have ninja files? ninja.rules or similar?

Comment: Have you tried opening DecisionTree.sln in Visual Studio?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes i see one file with same name.

Comment: Good! This is default build target for Cmake, I believe. You could either install in VS 2019 CMake support and it will bring Ninja, or go to https://ninja-build.org/ and download it itself. After you got ninja.exe in your path, you could in dev.prompt do something like `ninja -f build.ninja` and your software would be building

Comment: Also, we would need to see the contents of test/build, since that is where the cmake generated files are placed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Visual Studio 2019 you will want to run your cmake (from the build directory) as

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ..
```

and you will get a new configuration and `.sln` generated in your build folder.

From there you can open the `.sln` in visual studio, or run (in your build directory)

```
cmake --build .
```

to begin compilation of a debug build or

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

for a release build.

Comment: The problem with visual basic is that when i open .sln in IDE and try to build it, i get error `invalid numeric argument /weffc++`. This is mentioned in `CMakeList.txt`

Comment: `target_compile_options(DecisionTreeTest PRIVATE -Wall -Weffc++ -Wpedantic)`

Comment: Weffc++ is a GCC flag, it's not supposed to be used with Microsoft's C++ compiler (MSVC).